# How to put value to class array in Javascript on procesing

Tags: javascript, processing

```
public_class st
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int infected;
}
st[][] n = new st[25][25];
void setup()
{
  n[1][1].x=1;
  n[1][1]=(1,1,1);
}
```

I learned c++ and I want to use class on processing. But I don't know how to put value on class array. Can you explain how to put value to class array or How to use struct on processing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an **instance** of your class before you can set the fields in the instance. Something like this:

```
void setup()
{
  n[1][1] = new st();
  n[1][1].x=1;
  n[1][1]=(1,1,1);

}
```

By the way, you should also get into the habit of giving your classes and variables more descriptive names. Classes should also start with an upper-case letter.

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/creating-classes) is a tutorial on creating classes in Processing.